# got error when try to fetch some data from open weather api

Tags: node.js, express

This app is to get small piece of data from open weather map through api,  app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require('https');
const app = express();
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Khartoum&appid=d244334364579178494bb3c4528e218b&units=metric"
 
    https.get(url, function (response) {
        response.on("data", function (data) {
            const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
            res.write(weatherData.weather[0].description);
            res.write(weatherData.weather[0].id);
 
            res.send();
        });
    });
});
app.listen("3000", function () {
    console.log("runnign on port 3000.");
});
```

the error that triggered in terminal when I reloaded the page:

```
_http_outgoing.js:671
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument',
    ^
 
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received type number (804)
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:671:11)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:636:15)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/foola/Desktop/appBrewery/WeatherProject/app.js:18:17)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:512:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:985:34)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:966:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
```

***So what's the wrong here exactly?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mybe `weatherData.weather[0].id` is a number type likely integer?
try

```
res.write(weatherData.weather[0].id+'');
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicated, `res.write` accepts buffer or string only, `weatherData.weather[0].id` is of type int/number, therefore you might want to stringify it first before passing it to `res.write`.

```
res.write(weatherData.weather[0].id.toString())
```